# How can I use a table.column value for a join using dynamic sql?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm creating a data validation procedure for a database, using various models, etc. in the database.

I've created a temp table with a model, a sequence, and 3 columns.
In each of these columns I have the qualified column name (table.column) to use in my query, or a null value.  Here's the temp_table structure:

```
create table #temp_table(model nvarchar(50), seq nvarchar(50), col nvarchar(100), col2 nvarchar(100) , col3  nvarchar(100))
```

In my dynamic sql I have a join something like this (exteremely simplified):

```
select *
from 
      original_table
inner join
...
      #temp_table
on
      original_table.models = #temp_table.models
inner join
      set_model
on    
      original_tables.models = set_model.models
and   #temp_table.col = set_model.val
and   #temp_table.col2 = set_model.val2
and   #temp_table.col3 = set_model.val3
```

What I'm working on has many more tables (hence the ... in the middle of the query), so, we'll just assume that all the tables are present and all the columns are valid.

Because #temp_table.col stores a value, when being join to set_model.val the comparison will look something like `'Buildings.year_id' = 2014`.

Is there a way to force my dynamic query to use the value in #temp_table.col as part of the join condition?

For example:

If in the query above `#temp_table.col = 'Buildings.year_id'`
how do I make the join evaluate `Buildings.year_id = set_model.val`
rather than `'Buildings.year_id' = 2014`?

Comment: if you're already using dynamic SQL, why do you need the '' around the table name when you're building the string? `mSQL = "SELECT * From " + table.column + " WHERE X=Y"`  then `execute mSQL`

Comment: It's because the table.column value changes based on the model, which changes based on the row.

Comment: With dynamic SQL you're building a string and then executing the string.  in the above case the string results from your query are then built into the string and then executed.  This has the downfall of not being pre-compiled so execution time will take longer.  SQL injection can also occur if the table.column name data is not sanitized properly.  But in concept this works.  Here's an example: http://sqlusa.com/bestpractices/training/scripts/dynamicsql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to create a query which had a different query plan based upon the row queried.
I found a workaround (creating a cursor and looping through n different tables and appending each dynamic query with a ' union '), but I came back and thought about the problem I ran into for a little while.

I realized that I was trying to dynamically create a query based upon data from the query I was using.  As a result, no effective query plan could be created, as it would need to run a unique query based upon **each row**.

If the query had been able to work, it would've been *extremely* inefficient (as each row would make its own 'select' statement).

Regardless, the question itself was based on bad/incomplete logic.